# Use a specific type of font for writing a thesis

Tags: fonts, packages

I am using Texmaker (book class) to write my thesis, I want to use the font like in the image below:
[image]
can someone tell me what is the type of the font in the image and how can I declare it in latex.

Comment: do you have the pdf of that document? If so the document properties will show which font it is

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919/5764)